# is it possible to add images in between the text view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an application. It consists of notes and images also. I'm unable to find the best way of coding to add images and text together.

I want to add the images between the textview and after that, the text has to continue. Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be better to use a webview and load in some static html from the application unless you particularly need textviews, in which case look at holding things in UITableView